# pointer initialization and allocation issue

Tags: c++, pointers

I don't understand this:

compiler is fine with

```
int *p_x=&x;
```

but not this

```
int *p_x,x;
*p_x=&x;
```

It is confusing to me. What is the difference? Is this only a initialization convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token `*` has two meanings.

In the second example it is the dereferencing operator, which gets the value a pointer points to:

```
int *p_x,x;
*p_x=&x;
```

`p_x` is a pointer to `int`.

`x` is an `int`.

`&x` is the address of `x` (pointer to `int`).

`*p_x` is the value `p_x` points to (an `int`). `*` here is the dereference operator.

You are trying to assign a pointer `&x` to an `int`.

In the first example `int *p_x = &x` the token `*` actually belongs to the type, which is `int*`, a pointer to `int`. It is not the dereferencing operator here. Therefore the assignment is to `p_x` and not to `*p_x`. This becomes clearer if you write the line as `int* p_x = &x`. Assigning `&x` to `p_x` is fine, because both are of type  pointer/address to `int`.

The simplest way to fix the second example is to rewrite `*p_x = &x` to `p_x = &x`. Then `&x` is again assigned to the pointer instead of the value the pointer points to.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
int *p_x=&x;
```

You're declaring `p_x` as a pointer to `int` and assigning the value of `p_x` to the address of  `x` which is legal.

But here:

```
int *p_x,x;
*p_x=&x;
```

You're declaring `p_x` as a pointer to `int` and `x` as an integer. Then you're trying to assigne the address of `x` to the object pointed to by `p_x` which means, assigning the address of `x` to `x` which is not legal as `x` is not a pointer. And it will generate an error: `invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *p_x,x;
```

Is the equivalent of:

```
int *p_x;
int x;
```

So you actually want to remove the leading `*` for this to be valid:

```
p_x = &x;
```

This is essentially the same as `int *p_x=&x;`, I would punctuate this as `int* p_x = &x` to clarify that `p_x` is of type `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *p_x=&x;
```

Make a variable named p_x type (int *) (which is pointer to integer) and then set its value to  the address of x.

```
int *p_x,x;
*p_x=&x;
```

Make a variable named p_x type (int *) (which is pointer to integer, or in other words an address) and a variable named x type integer.

Where p_x is pointing (random location, because it wasn't initialized), put the address of x;

It's unfortunate that pointer types are defined with * and to access an address you also use *.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is common (and I use it myself):

```
int *p;
```

it's actually a little misleading. We're not declaring an `int` named "*p", we're declaring an `int*` named "p".

This:

```
int *p_x=&x;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
int* p_x;
p_x=&x;    // perfectly correct
```

But this is incorrect:

```
int *p_x,x;
*p_x=&x;   // ouch!
```

You're assigning an address to an int (and even if you cast it correctly, you're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, which causes Undefined Behavior).